# Running fetch API in local windows machine by using visual studio code

Tags: javascript

I am totally new to web development if somebody can help me to start to use Fetch API.
Can I run the HTML and vanilla JS (with JS Fetch API functionality) on my windows computer?
I was looking around and found visual studio code and a live server. It looks like it can load the page on the server but still, it is not clear what kind of JS library I should include for enabling Fetch API. I just want to execute the following code on my laptop (would be nice if I don't use any JS library though I am not sure if it is possible or not)

```
<script>
let file = "fetch_info.txt"  //assuming the file is located in my server

fetch (file)
.then(x => x.text())
.then(y => document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that the fetch method needs a proper resource path, example:

```js
fetch("cdn.example.org/files/fetch_info.txt")
```

Replace `cdn.example.org/files/fetch_info.txt` with the path of your file, in your case it would most likely be on localhost!

Read more about the fetch method on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch)

Comment: Thanks,  If I make a request new Request('flowers.jpg'); then it works but if I do with a remote new Request('https://hemelix.com/flowers.jpg');  then it does not work. If I put the URL to the browser address then I can see the image, how can I make it work?

Comment: What error do you see in the javascript console?

Comment: I get this: Access to fetch at 'https://www.hemelix.com/myjson.json' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: If I use  mode: 'no-cors', then I don't get the same error but I get Error: HTTP error, status = 0